# Is it possible to update rows from a key/value pair?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Explaining by example:

```
UPDATE Table SET value=(22,55,99) WHERE id IN (2,5,9)
```

So the row with `id=2`, `value` is set to `22`. And the row with `id=5`, `value` is set to `55`. Etc.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use derived table:

```
update t set
    value = a.value
from Table as t
    inner join (values
        (22, 2),
        (55, 5),
        (99, 9)
    ) as a(id, value) on a.id = t.id
```

For me this is the most elegant way to do this and it's also easily extandable (you can add more columns if you like)

Comment: To use it in postgresql with psycopg2 I had to change a bit this expresion. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71739300/psycopg2-errors-undefinedtable-relation-does-not-exist-join-table

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but not like you have:

```
UPDATE Table
SET value=case when id=2 then 22 when id=5 then 55 when id=9 then 99 end
WHERE id in (2,5,9)
```

If you have to do this for a large number of fields/records, you'd be better off just issuing a bunch of dedicated `update` queries.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` expression to chose update value:

```
UPDATE Table SET value = case id when 2 then 22
                                 when 5 then 55
                                 when 9 then 99
                         end
WHERE id IN (2,5,9)
```